# Three.js - Chrome new update issue

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, three.js

This morning I have opened my Chrome browser...
He was automatically update to a newer version : 17.0.963.46

Now after the update my three.js project not working properly...
The textures (images *.png) not loaded

I tried to run the same project on FireFox and it is working...very slow
but working...

Is anybody knows what is the bug/issue..or what it can be related to?

Comment: Can you post some example code?

Comment: It would also be a good idea to try your code under the most recent Chrome Canary release, which is built from trunk daily: https://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs

Answer (score 0):

I had problems running some of my projects in three.js from the browser. Are you by chance opening from a directory located on your hard drive. I had a project running fine when I previewed it in eclipse, but then when opened in Chrome it still ran but did not have the textures. I read a post somewhere about that if some format textures are not located on an actual webserver they will throw errors when trying to be loaded in Chrome. I have no idea why this is so as I figured you should be able to load any image from the HD without being connected to the internet. But sure enough I loaded up Apache2 on my Linux box and ran it from localhost and there were my textures again.